# zingchart data grouping and down sampling

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, zingchart

I'm currently building an application with zingchart with vary large set of data(500,000 pts plus). It has great performance, however, I found that there seems to be doing some data grouping or downsampling to enhance the performance. When this happens, the data is not rendered or displayed correctly.

Is there a way I can turn this feature off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
plot: {
  exact:true
  ...
}
```

will do the trick. Any and all modifications you will need (for this issue) will be inside of the `plot` [object](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/plot/).

One plot example, if you have many nodes you can turn off events for a majority of the nodes with `maxTrackers:1000`. This would benefit performance and as you zoom in you will get the events back on the 1000 nodes in view. I bring this up so you know there is a lot more configurability than you currently know about, so feel free to ask more questions!

Answer (score 1):

"plot" : {
    ....
    "exact" : true,
    "smart-sampling":true,
    ....
}

Leaving just exact:true will paint all nodes (500K) so it will be slow. The smart sampling will sample the data, but in such a way that you will see spikes that you would otherwise miss on a "blind sampling"